# How to extract p values from a vector with multiple anova

Tags: r, extract, anova

Using R, I created a vector with 39 anovas using the following script

```
w3<-lapply(split(q1, q1$taxa), aov, formula=trig ~ d)
```

I can extract p values from each of them separately via summary(w3$"type") but how can I do it for all 39 at once, preferably writing all the p values in a separate data frame?

Also, it is possible to create a list with a summary for each individual anova with

```
e7<-lapply(w3, FUN=summary)
```

but is there a way to make a data frame with p values from this list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sapply` to iterate over each anova and extract p-value.

```
sapply(w3, function(x) summary(x)[[1]][["Pr(>F)"]][[1]])
```

---

Using reproducible example with `mtcars`

```
w3 <- lapply(split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl), aov, formula=mpg ~ am) 
sapply(w3, function(x) summary(x)[[1]][["Pr(>F)"]][[1]])

#     4      6      8 
#0.0892 0.2209 0.8662
```

Comment: Thank you very much, if I apply several independent variables in this analysis, I cannot extract the p values after the second one (the second one I can extract just substituting last 1 with 2), would  you please explain what am I doing wrong? (the error is: Error in summary(x)[[1]][["Pr(>F)"]][[3]] : subscript out of bounds)

Comment: It is difficult to help without reproducible data since I don't know what structure you have in w3. Can you share dput(w3) ? You get that error because there is no value at `[[2]]` or `[[3]]` for certain data.

Comment: the data table is pretty huge, so I am not sure if I can paste it here, but to simplify it is the list with anova models, if I take one of them with {summary} function it looks like this:             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
d             8  12.10  1.5126   7.557 1.02e-08 ***
abundance     1   0.05  0.0467   0.233    0.630    
d:abundance   8   1.43  0.1789   0.894    0.523

Comment: Why do you need to substitute last 1 with 2? This should always remain `[[1]]`. What happens when you run `sapply(w3, function(x) summary(x)[[1]][["Pr(>F)"]][[1]])` as it is?

Comment: it gives the p value for the first independent variable perfectly fine, I was just trying to make it work for multivariate anova, and extract p value for  d*abundance , thank you very much for helping me though

Comment: using your example with mtcars: w3 <- lapply(split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl), aov, formula=mpg ~ am*hp)

Comment: so I was trying to extract p values for am*hp interractive effect, which I assumed should have position 3 but I am wrong

Comment: Remove `[[1]]` from it. Try `sapply(w3, function(x) summary(x)[[1]][["Pr(>F)"]])`

Comment: Great! It did it, I tried the same approach but did not put the last ) , thank you so much!!!